# writing a method which returns an iterator from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I am using blueJ to write this. What I am trying to do is ddd a method called `getUserIterator()` to `UserGroup` that `returns an Iterator` from the `ArrayList` and use the `Iterator` returned by my method to loop through the existing Users and add any users whose `userType` is `"admin"` to the administrators group.I am not sure how to do this!! My code below:

User Class:

```
package user; 
public class User{
    public enum UserType{                          
        ADMIN, EDITOR, USER;
    }

    private String id;                            
    private UserType userPermissions;              
    private String actualName;                     

    public User(String username, UserType userType, String name){
        id = username;
        userPermissions = userType;
        actualName= name;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return id;
    }

    public UserType getUserType(){
        return userPermissions;
    }       

    public String getName(){
        return actualName;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType input){
        userPermissions = input;
    }
}
```

and the userGroup class is:

```
package user;
import java.util.*;
import user.User.UserType; 

public class UserGroup{

    private ArrayList<User> people;

    public UserGroup(){
        people = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    public void addSampleData(){
        people.add(new User("jar1g13", UserType.ADMIN,"Jonny"));
        people.add(new User("ao9", UserType.EDITOR,"Aniruddh"));
        people.add(new User("pe6", UserType.USER,"Peter"));
        people.add(new User("mat73", UserType.USER,"Matthew"));
        people.add(new User("ora69", UserType.EDITOR,"Oranthi"));
        people.add(new User("ben12", UserType.USER,"Benedict"));
        people.add(new User("cam30", UserType.ADMIN,"Cambyse"));
        people.add(new User("are20", UserType.USER,"Alex"));
        people.add(new User("lim19", UserType.USER,"Liam"));
        people.add(new User("ada13", UserType.EDITOR,"Adam"));
    } 

    public User getUser(int idx){
        return people.get(idx);
    }

    public void printUsernames(){
        for (User user: people){
            System.out.printf("%s %s\n", user.getUsername(), user.getUserType());
        }
    }

    public void removeFirstUser(){
        people.remove(0);
    }

    public void removeLastUser(){
        people.remove(people.size()-1);
    }

    public void removeUser(String username){
        Iterator<User> itr = people.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()){
            User element = (User) itr.next();
            if (element.getUsername().equals(username)){
                itr.remove();                                       
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
package user;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        UserGroup grp = new UserGroup();          
        grp.addSampleData();                       
        grp.printUsernames();                      
    }

    public static void admins(){
        UserGroup administrators - new UserGroup(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with this code? what's not working, or is missing?

Comment: I don't see your `getUserIterator()` method anywhere.

Comment: You already asked a question for the remove() method, and didn't show any attempt at coding it by yourself. We won't do all your homework for you. Try something. Read documentation. And if you're stuck, post what you tried and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest you override `equals` and `hashCode` and use the `remove()` method on the `List` rather than rolling your own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it as

```
public class UserGroup implements Iterable<User> {
    private final List<User> people = new ArrayList<User>();

    public Iterator<User> iterator() {
        return people.iterator();
    }
    // OR to prevent the list being modified.
    public Iterator<User> iterator() {
        return Collections.unmodifableList(people).iterator();
    }
    // OR for extra paranoia
    public Iterator<User> iterator() {
        return Collections.unmodifableList(new ArrayList<Person>(people)).iterator();
    }
    // OR for even more paranoia
    public Iterator<User> iterator() {
        List<People> ret = new ArrayList<People>();
        for(People p : people)
            ret.add(new Person(p)); // take a deep copy.
        return Collections.unmodifableList(ret).iterator();
    }
}

// later
UserGroup userGroup = ...
for(User u : userGroup) {
   // do something with u
}
```

This assumes you don't need to worry about your caller modifying the list (which is should never do, but some people worry about such things)

Comment: Seems better, the name usergroup already makes it sound like a collection so implementing the interface is clearer, +1

Comment: One could always wrap `people` in an `unmodifiableList` before getting the `iterator` if one were paranoid.

Comment: @BoristheSpider +1 Even though you shouldn't need to do this, it is useful to list some of the options in case you do.

Answer (score 1):

You need a

```
public Iterator<User> getIterator(){
  return people.iterator;
}
```

In class `UserGroup`, you can then access it in any other class (or method) that deals with iterating over the users in the list and doing things like checking if their type corresponds to a given type (like you want to do with admins).